# How to get tags of questions answered by a user in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, sql, database

I can't solve this problem: using a remote DBMS from the Stack Overflow site (URL: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). Write a SQL query that displays the names of users with a reputation of more than 100 who have ever answered questions with the tag “sql” and “java”.

---

All I can do now is print names with a reputation greater than 100:

`select DisplayName, Reputation from Users where Reputation > 100`

How can I get tags of questions answered by a user in Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Comment: Re *"Write a SQL query"*: So it is a homework problem for a relational database class? Isn't the use of SEDE incidental (it happens to be a publicly accessible service with a (huge) data set)? That is, it really belongs on another site, like Stack Overflow?

Comment: It was [posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279866/how-to-get-tags-of-questions-answered-by-a-user-in-stackexchange-dataexplorer) about two hours prior.

Comment: Yes, I confused where to ask a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query like this needs a lot of [JOINs](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-joins), from users to answers to questions to tags. I wasn't convinced that would work on a database as large as Stack Overflow's, but [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1595926/users-above-a-certain-reputation-level-with-answers-to-questions-in-specific-tags?Tags=sql%2Cjava&MinimumReputation=100) nevertheless returns what you're looking for:

[image]